# ERR_SSL_VERSION_INTERFERENCE error when using fiddler with mono on ubuntu

Tags: 17.10, mono, certificates

I'm trying to intercept network requests using [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/fiddler-for-linux-beta-is-here) on Ubuntu 17.10 and mono 4.6.2. As per instructions given [here](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/fiddler-for-linux-beta-is-here)  I've also imported certificates by running command `mozroots --import --sync`. But after launching it I'm facing `ERR_SSL_VERSION_INTERFERENCE` visiting websites with `https`.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I am facing this issue now. Did you find the solution for this?

Comment: I could not find one.

Answer (score 1):

The [article](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/fiddler-for-linux-beta-is-here) OP given lists some limitations and problems

> TLS 1.1 and 1.2 Not Supported This is a hard limitation introduced by
>   the current state of TLS implementation in the Mono framework. So
>   Fiddler for Linux cannot use these protocols at present.

We conclude that mono-fiddler only support tls1.0, which means when curl connect to server directly, it will be like this:

```
* Connected to pi.com (127.0.0.1) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
```

Obviously, they use tls1.2 and http1.1 as negotiation result.
However, When curl use mono-fiddler as proxy, the result will be different:

```
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 8888 (#0)
* allocate connect buffer!
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to pi.com:443
> CONNECT pi.com:443 HTTP/1.1
> Host: pi.com:443
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 Connection Established
< FiddlerGateway: Direct
< StartTime: 18:08:06.731
< Connection: close
< 
* Proxy replied 200 to CONNECT request
* CONNECT phase completed!
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* CONNECT phase completed!
* CONNECT phase completed!
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.0 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.0 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.0 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.0 / AES256-SHA
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
```

They use tls1.0, even worse http1.0. The most awful thing is Chrome deprecated tls1.0 and tls1.1 since v72.0.xxx for some security stratege. So Chrome reports ssl version mismatching.

> SSL/TLS Handshake Properties Not Available Fiddler for Linux cannot
>   display these at present. This is a work in progress.

This will result in SSL_ERROR_RX_MALFORMED_SERVER_HELLO when Firefox use mono-fiddler as proxy.